# How to make text fields visible upon button click?

Tags: java, jframe

I have two text fields that I make invisible when the form is initialised. 
What I want to happen is the following.

[image]

and then when the button is clicked, they appear like so.

[image]

I have tried making the text fields not visible when the form initialised then triggering a action performed event when the button is clicked making the text fields visible again.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Weather extends javax.swing.JFrame {


            public Weather() {
            initComponents();
            this.jTextField3.setVisible(false);
            this.jTextField10.setVisible(false);



 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    this.jTextField10.setVisible(true);
    this.jTextField3.setVisible(true);
}                                       

     public static void main(String args[]) {


    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Weather().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
etc.. 
etc...

}
```

In C#, this method of making things visible and invisible works but the same logic doesn't apply to java. Nothing happens when I click the button. The two text fields just stay invisible.

When I don't make the text fields not visible when the form is initialised and make them invisible upon button click via the button clicked actionevent method, it works.

```
   private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    this.jTextField10.setVisible(false);
    this.jTextField3.setVisible(false);
}
```

Why can I only make the text fields invisible via button click but I can't make the text fields visible via button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because the window and the GUI was already created with the buttons invisible. When you just set them to visible true it doesn't know how to rewrite them. You can try:

```
this.revalidate();  //Here this being the jframe
this.repaint();
```